# MonoTouch.Dialog - EntryElement not allowing edit of typed in text

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I create a simple `EntryElement` "eNote" and add it to a `Section`. Super simple.

```
        Section secNote = new Section ("Notes");
        eNote.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None;
        eNote.AutocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No;
        eNote.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable;
        secNote.Add (eNote);
```

We type in a sentence like this:

[image]

Then when I try to add the text "I Like" before "Unity" by tapping before the "U", the first letter gets entered, but the rest gets put at the end of the text. The result is we can't edit text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression caused by [this change](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/commit/4cffe144f89fc9fbfe032d56e67a8583c2d641bf). If you build MonoTouch.Dialog from source (github) then you can revert the **4cffe144f89fc9fbfe032d56e67a8583c2d641bf** commit.

The same change also had other side effects, e.g. [#4736](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4736), beside the [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4972) you filled. You should check if this affects your application (or not) to see if the workaround is better than the revert.

Comment: I'll wait until MT.Dialog is updated with all the code, we have to only use production releases in our Enterprise builds

Comment: 37236b68f4c8fc6630e3ac28dd02beb6b5275c33 has a different fix that solves this (without reverting the fix for the original issue). This should be part of the upcoming 5.2.12 release (unless QA finds issues with it). Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that this is a bug and it should be filed with [Xamarin](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/)

However I did find a workaround.  Using the assembly browser you can "borrow" the existing implementation of the EntryElement and change the Value property to the following.

```
public string Value
{
    get
    {
        return this.val;
    }
    set
    {
        this.val = value;
        if (this.entry != null && value != null && !value.Equals (this.entry.Text))
        {
            this.entry.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Happy Hacking!